# JBoss and IntelliJ - Use Jboss Plugin to run and deploy or use Maven

Tags: java, maven, jboss, intellij-idea

I am a newbie in setting up a Java EE application in IntelliJ. I manage to make it work and deploy it using the plain Run Configuraiton > JBoss settings. But I want to convert my project into a maven project. I would just like to ask the difference between:

(1)building and running a web/ear application using IntelliJ Jboss plugin and creating a server run configuration, and

(2)using maven + jboss maven plugin to build, deploy, and run the server

Can I use the features of the IntelliJ JBoss plugin if I deploy using maven instead (such as hotdeploy and viewing the output of the server directly in intellj)?

Thanks a lot!